# Can Nextflow pipeline check the process executor type during running?

Tags: nextflow

I am running one Nextflow script in different environments (AWS batch, slurm...). I want to check if the `process.executor` is `awsbatch` during running. But I cannot call `process` directly. It raises the error `No such variable: process`. Are there any ways to check or print out the executor type for Nextflow pipeline job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a process instance (task), you can obtain this info through the `$task.executor` implicit variable. Check the example below:

```
process FOO {
  debug true

  script:
  """
  echo $task.executor
  """
}

workflow {
  FOO()
}
```

It outputs:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.02.0-edge
Launching `asd.nf` [naughty_yonath] DSL2 - revision: 2995f22831
executor >  local (1)
[99/f57ab8] process > FOO [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
local
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Are there any documents about `task` contents? I cannot find the detail of it in the official document.

Comment: And if I want to check `task. executor` in a function rather than the script, the `task` cannot be found.

Comment: You can only access task information within the task (process instance), so you won't be able to do it in a function that lies outside the process scope. `executor` is a process directive like any other, so you can get the full list here: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#directives